# PHP not showing one variable on WordPress page

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I am trying to add text in an image overlay. The page shows all other variables for the correct posts. But the status variable only shows the first text on all images e.g. NEW ARRIVAL

Variable

```
$status = 'NEW'; $status2='SOLD'; $status3='HOT DEAL';
```

Display Code

```
<div class="image-overlay"><?php $status = get_field('status'); if ($status='NEW') echo 'NEW ARRIVAL'; else { the_field('status');} ?></div>
```

I have tried other code like,

```
echo ('$status')
```

etc

```
<?php
unset($bed); unset($type); unset($salerent); unset($pricemin); unset($pricemax); unset($status);
$salerent = 'sale';
$salerent2 = 'rent';
$type = 'villa'; $type2='condo'; $type3='house'; $type4='land';
$status = 'NEW'; $status2='SOLD'; $status3='HOT DEAL';
$bed = 'all';
$minprice='0';
$maxprice='999999999';
if ($bed=='all') {$bed1=1;$bed2=2;$bed3=3;$bed4=4;$bed5=5;$bed6=6;$bed7=7;$bed8=8;$bed9=9;$bed10=10;}
if ($salerent=='rent'){
$p0text="Price (per month)";
$p1text="0 - 10,000";
$p2text="10,000 - 25,000";
$p3text="25,000 - 40,000";
$p4text="40,000 - 80,000";
$p5text="80,000+";  
}
else{
$p0text="Price";
$p1text="0 - 3 mill";
$p2text="3 - 6 mill";
$p3text="6 - 10 mill";
$p4text="10 - 20 mill";
$p5text="20+ mill"; 
}
?>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include( get_template_directory() . '/menu.php'); ?>  
    <!-- Main-->
    <main>
    <!-- Main Container-->
    <div class='container '>


<div class="row" style="vertical-align:bottom;">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center"><h1 class="hometitle"><span style="font-size:1.1em; color:red; position:absolute; margin-left:-4px; margin-top:-19px;  transform: rotate(25deg);">/</span>star property<br /><span class="mainsub"> Villas, Condos &amp; Houses for Sale &amp; Rent in Hua Hin</span></h1></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 center-on-small-only text-center">
    <div class="row searchbox">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <form id="searchurl" method="POST" action="http:// .com/search-result/?">
    <span class="filter">Search:</span>
    <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="salerent" name="salerent">
    <option value="sale" <?php if($salerent=='sale'){echo "selected";}?>>Sale</option>
    <option value="rent" <?php if($salerent=='rent'){echo "selected";}?>>Rent</option>
    </select>

    <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="type" name="type">
    <option value="villa" <?php if ($type=='villa'){echo "selected";}?>>Villa</option>
    <option value="condo" <?php if ($type=='condo'){echo "selected";}?>>Condo</option>
    <option value="house"<?php if ($type=='house'){echo "selected";}?>>House</option>
    <option value="house"<?php if ($type=='land'){echo "selected";}?>>Land</option>
    <option value="house"<?php if ($type=='commercial'){echo "selected";}?>>Commercial</option>
    </select>

    <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="bed" name="bed">
    <option value="all">Bedrooms</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>

    <select class="custom-select mysearch" id="pricerange" name="pricerange">
    <option id="p0" value="all"><?php echo $p0text;?></option>
    <option id="p1" value="1"><?php echo $p1text;?></option>
    <option id="p2" value="2"><?php echo $p2text;?></option>
    <option id="p3" value="3"><?php echo $p3text;?></option>
    <option id="p4" value="4"><?php echo $p4text;?></option>
    <option id="p5" value="5"><?php echo $p5text;?></option>
    </select>
<input class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 mysearch" type="text" id="searchid" name="searchid" placeholder="#ID/Project" />
<button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('searchurl').submit();" id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">SEARCH</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>  
    </div>



<div class="row zero col-lg-12 col-md-12 text-center">
<h2 style="width:100%; margin:0.8em 0 0.8em 0;">New Listings:<br /><span class="sub"> Properties for Sale &amp; Rent in Hua Hin</span></h2>
        </div>  
<div class="row" style="padding:0; margin:0;">

<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 6,
    'post__in' => array(22094, 16782, 20898, 19838, 22150, 1442, 1794),
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'no_paging' => true,
    'order' => DESC,
    'cat'           => 2,
);
// query
$the_query = new Wp_Query( $args ); ?>

 <ul id="starlistings" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 row" >
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<li class="col-lg-6 col-md-6" style="float:left; ">
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 listingframe" >
<div class="row" style="background-color:#77c0ff" "padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px">
<div class="text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12"><a class="listingslink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:0.8em;">
<div class="text-center col-lg-12 col-md-12" class="zero"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('image_1'); ?>" class="w-100" alt="<?php the_field('image_1_alt'); ?>" title="<?php the_field('area_project'); ?> <?php $type = get_field('type'); if ($type=='Villa') echo 'House'; else { the_field('type');} ?> for <?php the_field('sale_or_rent'); ?> in Hua Hin">**<div class="image-overlay"><?php $status = get_field('status'); if ($status='NEW') echo 'NEW ARRIVAL'; else { the_field('status');} ?></div>**</a>

</div>

</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center listingsdivider col-lg-12 col-md-12">
    <span>
<span class="listingsicons" style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0;">ID #<?php the_field('property_id'); ?></span>
    <span class="listingsicons" style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0;"><?php $price = get_field('Price'); echo number_format($price, 0, '', ','); ?> baht<?php $saleorrent = get_field('sale_or_rent'); if($saleorrent=='Rent'){echo ' ';} ?></span>
<span class="listingsicons"  style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0.5em;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/startheme/images/house.png" alt="house" style="height:12px; width:auto; margin:-4px 8px 0 0; padding:0; opacity:0.7" /><?php the_field('living_space'); ?> SQM</span>
<span class="listingsicons" style="padding:5px 0.5em 5px 0.5em;"><img src="/wp-content/themes/startheme/images/beds.png" alt="bedrooms" style="height:12px; width:auto; margin:-2px 4px 0 -3px; padding:0; opacity:0.6" /><?php the_field('bedrooms'); ?> Beds</span>
    <span style="padding:5px 0 5px 0.5em; "><img src="/wp-content/themes/startheme/images/bathrooms.png" alt="bathrooms" style="height:15px; width:auto; margin:-2px 6px 0 2px; padding:0; opacity:0.6;" /><?php the_field('bathrooms'); ?> Baths</span>
    </span>

<div style="background-color: white; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px"><span><?php $excerpt = wp_trim_words( get_field('property_description' ), $num_words = 10, $more = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">... more</a>' ); echo $excerpt; ?></span></div>
</div>
     </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would highly recommend that you use arrays instead of single variables that are loosely grouped by name ... I.E Instead of $p0text and all his friends use $ptext[0], $ptext[1] etc so all of your $ptext 's are grouped internally.  You need to discover arrays to make your life happy. Especially your $bed1 and $bed2 etc which should be a $bed array.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your code is...

```
 if ($status='NEW') echo 'NEW ARRIVAL';
```

Now you say that it is always showing "NEW ARRIVAL" which would mean that your IF is always TRUE.

What you are doing is assigning $status = "NEW" which will always be true.

Single = is assignment

Double == is checking for equivalence.

So your statement should be...

```
 if ($status =='NEW') echo 'NEW ARRIVAL';
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, Yes it always shows NEW ARRIVAL, but with double == nothing is showing in the image overlay. It's driving me crazy....

Comment: Well again looking at your code, I would be asking What is the result of a var_dump(the_field('status')); It's looking like its blank, empty or never set, so check where you are setting it and check the value where you want to use it.

Comment: This is more of an FYI... Why don't you mess about with it a bit. If you see something empty you can simple add some text in to test it. like "Oh it does get here" or something like that so you know 100% that bit of logic is working.

Comment: I have set the status var like so: unset($bed); unset($type); unset($salerent); unset($pricemin); unset($pricemax); unset($status);
$salerent = 'sale';
$salerent2 = 'rent';
$type = 'villa'; $type2='condo'; $type3='house'; $type4='land';
$status = 'NEW';                    But a var_dump still displays NULL

Comment: You need to close this and create a new question regarding why retrieving the field status from your DB query using get_field('status') is returning NULL.